# Is there a straightforward way to have a thread-local instance variable?

Tags: .net, multithreading, thread-safety, instance, threadstatic

With the `ThreadStatic` attribute I can have a `static` member of a class with one instance of the object per thread. This is really handy for achieving thread safety using types of objects that don't guarantee thread-safe instance methods (e.g., `System.Random`).

It only works for `static` members, though. Is there any straightforward way to declare a class member as thread-local, meaning, each class instance gets an object per thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243.aspx) class is what I was looking for.

And yes, I do feel a bit stupid for not knowing about this before now.

Comment: It's hardly stupid.  The .net libraries are very broad.  Only the very patient or very bored have read through the docs enough times to know everything that is available.  A general sense of the types of functionality available combined with google are the best way to find the bits you rarely need.